# Density of $C^{1}_{0}(\mathbb R)$ in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am looking for a counterexample to  $C^{1}_{0}(\mathbb R)$ ( $C^1$ functions with compact support) is dense in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$? Is there some easy counterexample showing that this latter is not true? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest counterexample is the non-zero constant function 
$$
f(x)=1.
$$
If $g\in C_0^1(\mathbb R)$, then $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}g(x)=0$, and hence
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)-g(x)|=\lim_{x\to\infty}|1-g(x)|=1.
$$
Thus
$$
\|f-g\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} |f(x)-g(x)|=1,
$$
and therefore $f$ can not be approximated by $C_0^1$ functions.

Comment: Many thanks ! that's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For any $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$, the $L^{\infty}$ norm of $f$ is the same as the $C(\mathbb{R})$ norm of $f$. So the closure of $C(\mathbb{R})$ in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ consists of all functions which are equal a.e. to continuous functions. Choose any function in $L^{\infty}$ which is not equal a.e. to a continuous function, and that function cannot be the $L^{\infty}$ limit a sequence in $C(\mathbb{R})$. A simple step function which is 1 on $[0,1]$ and is $0$ elsewhere is such a function.

Comment: I need C^1 functions.

Comment: If $f \in L^{\infty}$ is not in the closure of $C(\mathbb{R})$, it is not the in closure of a smaller subspace either.